# Como usar JQuery no projeto Cordova?

Tags: jquery, apache-cordova

Dei início a um projeto híbrido open source em HTML, CSS e JavaScript usando o Cordova. Adicionei o JQuery, mas não consigo usar seus recursos. Existe algum erro de minha parte?

 O código pode ser visualizado [aqui](https://github.com/Jedarc/horariofacil/blob/master/www/semestres.html).

Ao executar o projeto, a `linha 17`, por exemplo, não faz o que deveria (adicionar o texto dentro da `div` da `linha 26`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa chamar o código dentro de um [**`$(document).ready()`**](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) ou equivalente:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
     var curso = controller.getNomeCurso();
     $("#curso").text(curso);
  });
</script>
```